# Why won't certain photos or videos import into Photos?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I have a folder on my Mac with a variety of miscellaneous photos and videos.  All are standard format and open with Preview/QuickTime.  However when importing the folder, they are skipped.  A 2nd import shows all others imported except those and repeated attempts do not succeed.  No reason/error given by Photos app.

Comment: Just because Preview and QuickTime can open and read the file, doesn't mean it's "whitelisted" to be compatible with the Photos app/library. It should give you the path of the ignored files, are they images or videos?